# "Possible future event" or "future possible event"?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-phrases, adjective-order

There is this rule for adjective order in English, and mostly, authors agree on it. These are the two resources that I found online that tell us about this rule(there are others).

https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/adjective-order/

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order

If we want to be grammatically correct, which is the better option?

> "possible future event"
>
> or
>
> "future possible event"

I think the former is the correct one. Because then we can ask "Is the future event possible?". Then again we can also ask "Is the possible event in the future?". I would like to know your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a **possible future event**.

Looking at the 'order of adjectives' rule you quote, 'future' is a qualifier and so should come last before the noun.